# ElasticSearch updating all the documents

Tags: elasticsearch, autocomplete

I am using elasticsearch to implement autocomplete feature. I have an api from which I get a list of all the values for autocomplete and I put those as documents in elastic search. The problem I am having is, those values could change, not very often but once a week.

I am thinking of deleting the all the documents and updating those again once a week, same as ttl of a cache. Is there any better way to achieve this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there are a bit more elegant than deleting and updating, you could create a new index xxxx_V2, putting new docs into xxxx_v2, and use the alias to make your app code link to the new index, then delete old index.

ideas is from https://www.elastic.co/blog/changing-mapping-with-zero-downtime.